# How can I get the TSP tour from my function?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I can already find the "cost" of the tour with my code, but I would like know the tour that is being followed, for example my code is trying to find the lowest cost in this graph:

[image: graph]

but I want to know the tour, so ideally I would get either 1-2-4-3-1 or 1-3-4-2-1 both with a 80 of cost.
any way to modify the code to get one of those paths?
So instead of returning the cost or in my code the "min_path", I would like to return maybe a vector with the tour...

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

int travllingSalesmanProblem(vector<vector<int>> graph, int s, int n)
{
    vector<int> vertex;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (i != s)
            vertex.push_back(i);
    int min_path = INT_MAX;
    vector<int> solution_path;

    do {

        int current_pathweight = 0;

        int k = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex.size(); i++) {
            current_pathweight += graph[k][vertex[i]];
            //cout << graph[k][vertex[i]] << endl;
            k = vertex[i];
        }
        
        current_pathweight += graph[k][s];
        //cout << graph[k][s] << endl;


        min_path = min(min_path, current_pathweight);
    if(min_path == current_pathweight)
        solution_path = vertex;

    } while (
        next_permutation(vertex.begin(), vertex.end()));

    return min_path;
}

int main()
{
    int n =4;
    vector<vector<int>> graph =  { { 0, 10, 15, 20 },
                       { 10, 0, 35, 25 },
                       { 15, 35, 0, 30 },
                       { 20, 25, 30, 0 } };
    int s = 0;
    int solution = travllingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, n);
    cout << solution<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have done all the hard work already.
Two options:

1. Change the return type to `std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>`. The last line of your function then becomes:

```
return {min_path, solution_path};
```

The call can then become:

```
auto [solution, solution_path] = travllingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, n);
```

2. Take `std::vector<int>& solution_path` as a reference and update it with the smallest solution you find.
   The call then becomes:

```
std::vector<int> solution_path;
int solution = travllingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, n, solution_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you have presented, only minor change is required to show the  solution path. I believe that is code is not meant for professional setting. The assumptions made in the code makes it specific to these inputs provide and not generalised to solving TSP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

vector <int>  travllingSalesmanProblem(vector<vector<int>> graph, int s, int n)
{
    vector<int> vertex;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (i != s)
            vertex.push_back(i);
    int min_path = INT_MAX;
    vector<int> solution_path;

    do {

        int current_pathweight = 0;

        int k = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex.size(); i++) {
            current_pathweight += graph[k][vertex[i]];
            //cout << graph[k][vertex[i]] << endl;
            k = vertex[i];
        }
        
        current_pathweight += graph[k][s];
        //cout << graph[k][s] << endl;


        min_path = min(min_path, current_pathweight);
    if(min_path == current_pathweight)
        solution_path = vertex;

    } while (
        next_permutation(vertex.begin(), vertex.end()));

    return solution_path;
}

int main()
{
    int n =4;
    vector<vector<int>> graph =  { { 0, 10, 15, 20 },
                       { 10, 0, 35, 25 },
                       { 15, 35, 0, 30 },
                       { 20, 25, 30, 0 } };
    int s = 0;
    vector <int> solution = travllingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, n);
    cout << "{";
    for(int item: solution) 
      cout << item << "; ";
    
    cout << "} "<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```